# How to align banner image+text to the main site?

Tags: css

I want to position the banner photo+text in http://forum.emile-coue.org same way as in my drupal site: http://www.emile-coue.org.
I tried but could not do it. What'll be the simplest way to achieve it without changing the banner in the second drupal site?

Comment: Both sites look identical. Mainly because they both end up at the same URL. Is this a mistake?

Comment: Edited your second link to point to proper site. :)

Comment: sorry the second one is www.emile-coue.org

Comment: Yeah, you linked both to the forum. But for starters, in the non-forum site, you're making a huge mistake by trying to structure the header with a table (not to be mean, but this isn't the 90's anymore). Try doing it without the table structure, then it should all be pretty after a little css :)

Comment: I've not tinkered anything. The forum is from phpbb and the main site is drupal.

Comment: I'm assuming you can edit the html itself, though? A quick fix would be to set the width of the first `td` (with your image) to `width="100px"`. If you want it to be _exactly_ like your main site's header, including the link around the title, you'll have to do some more code editing.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your main site's code & did a few edits. This should get you what you want.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <h1 style="padding-top: 5px;">
      <a href="../index.php" style="text-decoration:none !important;">
        <img src="./styles/subsilver2/imageset/subgarland_logo.png" width="80" height="100" alt="" title="" style="float: left;">
        <span style="margin: 25px 0 0 100px; display: block; color: white;">Emile Coue</span>
      </a>
    </h1>
    <span class="gen" style="margin-left: 22px;">Forum dedicated to discussing Coue's method</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine to use `!important`. It's a way of pushing your styles to work over say a generated style sheet or a style sheet from a theme. For more on this you can check out SmashingMag's article (http://bit.ly/ke2nZs) or CSS-tricks post (http://bit.ly/iY2MZu), both deal with `!important` in detail.